# Iterate over two different non-binary tree graph

Tags: algorithms, search-trees

I'm working to solve a problem based on two non-binary tree graphs, that they need to be iterated together in order to find a valid combination.

I did a basic implementation that works, but it have a few flaws. Let me first explain a bit.

The point is that I have two trees, and each node have "n" children nodes, and that "n" child have another "n", and so on ("n" is constant, I mean for example if "n=14" then every node have 14 children and every child have another 14 children).

Also, that "n" value is constant and the same for both trees.

Having this concept, I need to find a combination of two nodes that fulfill some condition (that condition is user-specified, so for exapmple porpouse let's say we need to have two nodes with equal content).

I made an algotihm that iterates over all two trees, but it does in a parallel mode (I mean, if the solution is `root/node1/node2/node5` + `root/node3/node3/node14` it works, but having `root/node1/node2` + `root/node14` will not find it).

So, my algorithm does not cover 100% of valid posibilites. So my question is:

How can I iterate doing left/right join bewtween two trees?

Thank you

Comment: Could you summarize your code / transcribe it to pseudocode? It seems that you looking for algorithm, not implementation (that would be off-topic here), but not everyone knows Java, so it limits the chance to get answer.

Comment: @Evil I updated the code to look java-less, and more like an algorithm. Thanks for you appreciation.

Comment: That's a lot to read.  Can you find a more concise way to specify your problem?  Do you have a specific question?  Is your problem "given two trees, find a pair of nodes that have the same content" and your question "what is the most efficient algorithm for this?".  If so, can you edit the question to just say that?  Note that the algorithm for finding a pair of nodes with the same content might be different than the algorithm for finding a pair that meets some other condition.    "Asking for general help" is too open-ended and isn't a good fit here (see our [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: We're not interested in seeing code (especially a long block of code), and not everyone here knows Java.  Please remove the code and replace it with concise pseudocode and ideas.

Comment: @D.W. I updated my question. Thought that people will like to see some concise information, but looks like not, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate doing left/right join bewtween two trees"?  I don't understand what you are asking.  What's the definition of "left/right join"?  Often a helpful way to specify an algorithms problem is to describe the input, describe the output, and specify how the two must be related.  I understand that the input is a pair of trees with a value stored in each node.  But what is the desired output?  Do you want a pair of nodes that have the same value stored in them?  How do you want us to evaluate possible algorithms?  By their (asymptotic) running time?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) though st least there are some concepts that does not need explanation as theyare part from basic group-arithmetic. Anyway I solved the problem so I may close the question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48537992/781723